# Nightwatch/Cucumber - Scenario Outline and Example table not working

Tags: javascript, cucumber, nightwatch.js

I'm not a developer, so still learning javascript etc.
I have some automation scripts all up and running using Nightwatch/Cucumber. I'm now trying more complicated steps.
Scenario Outline with an Examples table. The issue I'm facing, I cannot get the test to pick up the data from the table. It gets to the step, then just starts again without actually populating. It looks like my step is not defined.
I am using PageObjects and this all works correctly except in this scenario. I'm not sure how to code the step correctly

Scenario Outline

```
When I create a new Lot 
Then I can create multiple Lots using a different <postcode>

Examples:
|postcode|
|WF4 5HQ |
|SA11 1DJ|
```

Step Definition

```
Then(/^I can create multiple lots using a different ([^\"]*)$/, (postcode) => {
return pageLotsMultiple
    .useXpath()
    .waitForElementVisible('//*[@id="__06a943c59f33a34bb5924aaf72cd2995"]/input')
    .pause(1000)
    .setPostcode(postcode)
```

I've tried various ways, and all do the same thing

```
Then(/^I can create multiple lots using a different ([^\"]*)$/, (postcode) => {
return pageLotsMultiple
    .setPostcode(postcode)
    .addProperty()
    .waitForElementVisible('@newPostcode')
    .newPostcode()
```

The test runs fine without the table and harcoding the postcodes, but I want to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

This is such a silly mistake that each one of us goes through. I will write yours as below with ***quotes***.

```
Scenario Outline: Scenario Name
When I create a new Lot
Then I can create multiple Lots using a different <postcode>

Examples:
  | postcode   |
  | "WF4 5HQ"  |
  | "SA11 1DJ" |
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, but it didn't help:

  `? Then I can create multiple Lots using a different "WF4 5HQ"
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         Then('I can create multiple Lots using a different {string}', function (string) {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });`

Comment: do you have this in repo or something where I can take a look?

Answer (score -1):

"Then I can create multiple Lots using a different" is not equal to "I can create multiple lots using a different". The case for lots is different.